# Point to Line for lines and polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, well-known-text, geometry-conversion

I have a csv file which I converted to points.  It contains features that are a mix of lines and polygons.  Format is below.  Now I would like to use the point to line processing tool to generate the lines and polygons.  Not sure if my csv format needs to be changed but it does not separate each feature.

[image]

Comment: do you know python? if so, that might be the best option to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to separate your data into two files, one each for lines and polygons.

After you have the data separated, I would suggest concatenating the coordinates into Well Known Text in an excel sheet. I use the formula and layout pictured below.
[image]

As you can see the format for WKT is 
"Geometry Type"(Long1 Lat1, Long2 Lat2,...,Long[n] Lat[n]) with [n] being the number of nodes along the line. The geometry types you would be after are "linestring" and "Polygon". With the formula formatted properly in your sheet you should be able to automatically generate a WKT string for each record with a drop down copy operation.
The final product of the process would be a column containing text strings similar to the following example.
Linestring(-82.7642 27.76782,-82.7642 27.76782)
The resulting line would show up on the west coast of Florida.

Comment: Awesome.  Let me give this a go.

Comment: Not working for me.  My format is: lat1 lon1 lat 2 lon2, etc.  Do the lat/lon pairs need to be in the same column?  So for a line with 4 points, you would have four columns, vs 8 columns?

Comment: The whole string needs to be in a single column no matter how many nodes are in the line. The purpose of the screen shot was only to illustrate how you can concatenate a series of points into the wkt format into the single column from a data set that contains multiple columns. It also looks like you are switching the order of the coordinates. The longitude needs to come first.